# Merge two PropertyInfo

Tags: vb.net

I've two structures and one class in my namespace `Dimension`. These structures are `Dimension.Derived` and `Dimension.Basis`. The class was called `Exponent`. I had overrided the Function `ToString()` of my class to get the `DisplayNameAttribute` of properties in my structure `Dimension.Derived`.

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String

     Dim oType As Type
     oType = GetType(Dimension.Derived)

     Dim colMemberInfo() As PropertyInfo = oType.GetProperties

     For Each oMemberInfo In colMemberInfo
         If Me = oMemberInfo.GetValue(oMemberInfo) Then
             Dim de As New Dimension.Exponent
             de = oMemberInfo.GetValue(oType)
             Dim attr() As DisplayNameAttribute = DirectCast(oMemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DisplayNameAttribute), False), DisplayNameAttribute())
             If attr.Length > 0 Then
                 Return attr(0).DisplayName
             Else
                 Exit For
             End If
         End If
     Next

     Return Nothing

 End Function
```

That works fine, but it should search through both structures. Therefore, I changed the first lines into

```
Dim oType1, oType2 As Type
oType1 = GetType(Dimension.Derived)
oType2 = GetType(Dimension.Basis)

Dim colMemberInfo() As PropertyInfo = oType1.GetProperties And oType2.GetProperties
```

But this throws an exception that the `And`-Operator is not declared for `PropertyInfo`. Surely I can repeat the For-Each-loop for the another structure, but that's not the intention. What should I do to merge these PropertyInfos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`And` is a boolean operator. It's for True/False values. You want to get a list of `PropertyInfo` from the two types, so try:

```
Dim properties as List(Of PropertyInfo) = New List(Of PropertyInfo)
properties.AddRange(oType1.GetProperties())
properties.AddRange(oType2.GetProperties())
```